# Stubbing a static method with JMockit using 'any'

Tags: java, collections, mocking, static-methods, jmockit

I want to test, whether `Collection.sort(...)` is called or not with [JMockit](https://code.google.com/p/jmockit/):

```
final List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
new Expectations() {
  {
    Collections.sort((List<Employee>) any);
    result = employees;
  }
};

assertThat(EmployeeRepository.getAllOrderedByName()).isSameAs(employees);
```

This is the implementation of my example repository under test:

```
public class EmployeeRepository {

  private static List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

  public static List<Employee> getAllOrderedByName() {
    Collections.sort(employees);
    return employees;
  }
}
```

When I run the unit test I get a NullPointerException at `Collections.sort`. It seems like it is a problem in the mocking it self since the debugger never reaches a break point in the `getAllOrderedByName` method.

How can I stub static methods using `any` with JMockit?

Comment: Is it on purpose that you return the list you sorted (which seems to be the list of the instance)?

Comment: No, this was a mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your test code, the `Collections` class is never specified to be mocked. Therefore, that `Collections.sort((List<Employee>) any);` call throws an NPE because the value of `any` is null and the actual `sort` method is executed.

You probably assumed that any method call inside an expectation block would be automatically mocked, but that's *not* how the JMockit API works. Instead, you need to explicitly specify which types are *mocked*, by declaring a mock field or a mock parameter annotated with `@Mocked`, `@NonStrict`, `@Cascading`, or `@Capturing`.

Also, in this case `Collections.sort` is a method that returns `void`, so it doesn't make sense to record a return value for it.

Furthermore, writing the test like this is not what I would recommend anyway. It should instead verify that the resulting collection is sorted, without ever mocking the `Collections` class.

Answer (score 1):

That does not answer your specific question (and I have had difficulties with `any` myself in the past so I try to avoid it!), but you could use a MockUp instead:

```
final AtomicBoolean wasCalled = new AtomicBoolean();

new MockUp<Collections> () {
    @Mock
    public <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) {
        wasCalled.set(true);
        //no-op otherwise
    }
};

assertThat(EmployeeRepository.getAllOrderedByName()).isSameAs(employees);
assertTrue(wasCalled.get());
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do it this way if I were you.

First, test that your `Comparable` on `Employee` works.

Then create mocks of your `Employee` class. Note: using mockito here, but I guess this can be adapted to jmockit (which I have never used):

```
private static final int NR_MOCKS = 20;

// ....

List<Employee> sorted = new ArrayList<>(NR_MOCKS);
for (int i = 0; i < NR_MOCKS; i++)
    sorted.add(mock(Employee.class));

// Create a shuffled list of the sorted list
List<Employee> shuffled = new ArrayList<>(sorted);
Collections.shuffe(shuffled);

// Inject shuffled into repository

// Stubs
for (int i1 = 0; i1 < NR_MOCKS; i1++)
    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < NR_MOCKS; i2++)
        when(sorted.get(i1).compareTo(sorted.get(i2))).thenReturn(i2 - i1);

List<Employee> actual = EmployeeRepository.getAllOrderedByName();

assertEquals(actual, sorted);
```

Not only does it check that the list is eventually sorted (since you have already tested your `Comparable` implementation beforehand), but you **don't care** what sorting algorithm is used; it Just Works(tm).